# Issues using Jsoup to connect to a webpage

Tags: java, html, jsoup

This is my first time using JSoup, and I am having an issue connecting to a url that I want to parse information out of.

The url:
http://uselectionatlas.org/RESULTS/national.php?f=1&year=2008&off=0&elect=0

I originally tried to do this, however I was getting a timeout exception

```
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://uselectionatlas.org/RESULTS/national.php?f=1&year=2008&off=0&elect=0").get();
```

Here is the exception:

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:152)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:275)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:687)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:633)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1324)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:468)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:575)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:548)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:235)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:224)
    at ParseData.main(ParseData.java:18)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

I did some research online and I found a method .timeout(0) which sets the Jsoup timeout to infinite.

Now when I try this

```
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://uselectionatlas.org/RESULTS/national.php?f=1&year=2008&off=0&elect=0").timeout(0).get();
```

I get the following exception:

```
org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=403, URL=http://uselectionatlas.org/RESULTS/national.php?f=1&year=2008&off=0&elect=0
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:598)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:548)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:235)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:224)
    at ParseData.main(ParseData.java:18)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

Could someone please point me in the right direction of how I should be loading this url into jsoup?

Answer (score 2):

A 403 error means the server is forbidding access.
You just need to add the UserAgent property to HTTP header as follows:

```
Jsoup.connect("http://uselectionatlas.org/RESULTS/national.php?f=1&year=2008&off=0&elect=0")
.userAgent("Mozilla/5.0")
.timeout(0).get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Some sites do not allow robots, that is what is happening for this site.
You have to add a user agent so it does not get restricted.